# google script insert as HTML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

If I have the string:

```
var text = "Altman, R. (1992). Sound space. In R. Altman (Ed.), <em>Sound Theory Sound Practice</em> (pp. 46–64). New York: Routledge.";
```

how can I insert this into google docs with the required italics intact?

```
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
cursor.insertText('here: ' + text);
```

inserts the text as is (without displaying italics and showing the `<em>...</em>`).

A few people have asked similar questions here without success mostly getting answers that relate to creating a new document using the Drive service (I want to insert HTML text anywhere in an existing document).

I've come across intriguing snippets such as:

```
var text = Utilities.newBlob("").setDataFromString(response.bibEntry, "UTF-8").setContentType("text/html");
```

or:

```
var text = doGet('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
function doGet(text) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(text);
}
```

but these appear to return objects which I've no idea how to use – trying to use insertText(text), I get 'Blob' and 'HtmlOutput' respectively.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because cross.posting is not allowed. (Already answered in Web Apps -> [google Script insert as HTML](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/151322/88163))

Comment: Fine. Not clear to me though that stackoverflow.com and webapps.stackexchange.com are related and thus subject to cross-posting rules.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking to do this, it appears it is [not possible](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/151322/google-script-insert-as-html). Text with HTML markup within it, must be broken up and each fragment styled separately with google script's routines before being stitched back together and inserted.